# AddOpenIdConnect error - SecurityTokenException: Unable to validate the 'id_token', no suitable ISecurityTokenValidator was found for: ''."

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, openid-connect

I am getting this exception in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app.
Those are parameters used:

```
                options.ClientId = config["Connection:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = config["Connection:ClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = config["Connection:Uri"];
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin");
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.ResponseMode = "query";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
```

I get both authorization code and access token, but after that I get error message as shown:

> Unable to validate the 'id_token', no suitable ISecurityTokenValidator was found for: ''."

Why is this validation for "id_token" occurring even tough I am using "code" as a response type?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used them, the Microsoft server side web app libraries only supported the hybrid flow and you had to set:

- response_type=code id_token

This forces id tokens to be validated as part of the authorization response, which adds to security in the area of substitution attacks.

A newer option for UIs is to use the following flow, in which case additional PKCE parameters are also needed, which I'm pretty sure the MS libraries do not support.

- response_type=code

In the aecond case the id token is received and processed in the following step that swaps the authorization code for tokens.